# CSS/HTML make all elements fit all resolutions

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and I'm trying to make all the elements fit all the resolutions. It looks fine on my computer, but on another computer with a different resolution, the website doesn't fit, it's either too big or too small.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="logonav.css" />
<title> Homepage </title>
</head>
<body class="Homepage">
<div id="container">
</div>
        <h1> <href="#" id="logo"><img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/327x238q90/911/g22OQa.png" alt> </a> </h1>

        <!-- Navigation bar -->

        <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
        <li class="horizontal">
            <a href="homepage.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="horizontal">
            <a href="products.html">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="horizontal">
            <a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="horizontal">
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

```
CSS:
    html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#container {
    background-image:      url("https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/846x529q90/910/6KfCc2.jpg");
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    }
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: 625px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
nav { 
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.horizontal {
    display: inline;
    margin: 100px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 30px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #C3943C;
}
li:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -10px;
    left: 730px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
li:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 48%;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -225px;
    right: 945px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: better use bootstrap framework.

Comment: See http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: i did download that but how do i apply it?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: There are many examples specified there..see http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: You will have to sit and go through the documentation

Comment: Forget bootstrap. Learn the basic principles of HTML and CSS first. Learn how to [validate](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) your markup.

Comment: Don't use bootstrap. It may do what you want but you won't know why and you won't learn anything. Instead, google for "responsive web" and "media queries" along with a lot of reading and practice.

Comment: bootstrap just messes up the whole site

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using CSS frameworks like Bootstrap or Foundation if the person which uses it tries to understand how they work underneath. Its far easier to learn from something that is doing thing the right way than learning from own mistakes.